# Image set cardinality vs set cardinality

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $S$ is the set of natural numbers $= \{1,2,3,4, \ldots\}$.

Consider the function $n^2 - n$

Does the image set $f(S)$ have the same cardinality as $S$?

I want to say no because the function is not a bijection, yet for every element in $S$, the function will produce an output.

Comment: Why do you think it is not a bijection?

Comment: sorry, instead lets consider the function f(x) = 2x. This function is injective, but not surjective. But does f(S) have the same cardinality as S?

Comment: By definition if u have a function $f:S \rightarrow f(S)$ then it is always a surjection since the very definition of  $f(S)$ is the image set! i.e. every point in $f(S)$ is landed by some point in $S$. Of course this can change if you decidedly change the codomain to some set larger than $f(S)$. So in any case if you already established surjectivity, it remains to show injectivity. If you have both, then we say both the domain and codomain have same cardinality.

Comment: Sets $A, B$ have the same cardinality iff there $exists$ at least one  bijection $\psi:A\to B.$ When $A$ is not finite, this does not preclude that there may  another function  $f:A \to B$ that is injective or surjective but not  bijective.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, we consider the function $f:S\rightarrow f(S)$ where $S$ is the set of natural numbers and $f(n)=n^2-n$ for all $n\in S$.

As per my comment above, this construction is always surjective. It thus remains to show injectivity. Suppose we have $n,m\in S$ such that $f(n)=f(m)$, i.e. $n^2-n=m^2-m$. Rearranging we have $(n-m)(n+m-1)= 0$.

Since $n$ and $m$ are both at least of value 1, then $n+m-1$ cannot be 0. So $n-m=0$ and so $n=m$. The function is injective and thus bijective. i.e. $S$ and $f(S)$ have the same cardinality.